# problem in deleting a node in linked list (Python)

Tags: python, linked-list

So below is a linked that removes an item from the list

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def remove(self,item_to_remove):
        n = self.head
        while n is not item_to_remove :
            n = n.next_node
        if n == item_to_remove:
            n = None
```

In the process of looping through the nodes it returns me this ERROR

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_node'
```

It would be great if you can help
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value in self.head before trying to iterate it. Initialization value of it is None, therefore trying to iterate through a None type object is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the remove method, try to insert data first.
Try the below method for inserting.

```
  def insert(self, data):
    newNode = Node(data)
    if(self.head):
      current = self.head
      while(current.next):
        current = current.next
      current.next = newNode
    else:
      self.head = newNode
```